# Django how to mark user-specific objects in queryset to be sent to template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

A newbie in the world of Django. I have what seems to be a general problem but I couldn't find a good answer on the Internet.I need to pass a django queryset to template to display a list. Of those Article objects, some may have been written by the user, I want to highlight/star those particular articles. What is the best practice/solution to achieve this?

for example:

```
 class Article(models.Model) :
   article_text = models.CharField(max=32)
   written_by = models.CharField()
```

So I can access the list of all articles in the views.py:

```
 article_list = Articles.objects.all()
```

And I can filter all the articles by my current logged in user as

```
 my_article = article_list.filter(written_by=current_user)
```

**Within Template I want to display a list of all articles, but 'star' only the ones which have been written by the current logged in user**

so in my template I want to do something like this:

```
{% for article in article_list %}
  {% if article.some_flag %}
        Starred Article
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Question: Is there a good way to annotate 'article_list' objects with a flag some_flag that marks 'my_articles' in views.py?

Or is there a way to do this within template by passing both article_list and mylist and doing the lookup inside the template code?
Something like (code for illustration only):

```
{% for article in article_list %}
  {% if article.pk in mylist.keys %}
        Starred Article {{ mylist.pk }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any pointers would be very helpful. Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly change your Article model to this:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Article(models.Model) :
    article_text = models.CharField(max=32)
    written_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Next in your template check if user is same as the request's user:

```
{% for article in article_list %}
    {% if article.written_by == request.user %}
        Starred Article
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Also it looks like you have some `current_user` (don't know what this variable is, perhaps the users username?) which you are using to match the users, if you really don't want to change your Model you can pass that into the context and write `{% if article.written_by == current_user %}`. But I would recommend to change the Article model for further ease while developing.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AbdulAzizBarkat. I think I got the general idea of how to do this. Looks like the solution is to do send only one queryset to the template and use Django db links to get to the desired objects. thanks